# Calculate quote volumes (for a financial instrument) within numeric constraints

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, python-3.x, finance

The function below is part of a trading system. Its purpose is to assign a volume (order size) to a bid (buy) quote and and ask (sell) quote, depending on the value of the `position_size` argument.

This trading system strictly cannot exceed a position limit of 100 in either direction, so our order volumes need to never exceed 100 when combined with the absolute value of `current position`.

However there is one caveat. Occasionally, for uncontrollable external reasons, a bid or ask (buy or sell order) will be executed twice before its price can be re-adjusted.

So any `bid_volume` or `ask_volume` returned by this function needs to be at most, half the value of 100 - `position_size`, in order to account for the occasional double execution.

Thats why at any step of the if-else blocks below, doubling the `ask_volume` or `bid_volume` plus `current_position` will not exceed 100.

**What is the fastest way to achieve this with Python, other than the below code?**

```
def adjust_volume(position_size):

    # Long.
    if position_size > 0:

        if position_size < 45:
            bid_volume = 45 - position_size
            ask_volume = 50

        elif position_size >= 45 and position_size < 65:
            bid_volume = 65 - position_size
            ask_volume = 50

        elif position_size >= 65 and position_size < 82:
            bid_volume = 82 - position_size
            ask_volume = 50

        elif position_size >= 82 and position_size < 100:
            bid_volume = 91 - position_size
            ask_volume = 85

    # Short.
    elif position_size < 0:

        abs_position_size = abs(position_size)

        if position_size > -45:
            bid_volume = 10
            ask_volume = 45 - abs_position_size

        elif position_size <= -45 and position_size > -65:
            bid_volume = 50
            ask_volume = 65 - abs_position_size

        elif position_size <= -65 and position_size > -82:
            bid_volume = 50
            ask_volume = 82 - abs_position_size

        elif position_size <= -82 and position_size > -100:
            bid_volume = 75
            ask_volume = 85 - abs_position_size

        elif position_size == 0:

            bid_volume = 30
            ask_volume = 30

    return position_size, bid_volume, ask_volume


position_size, bid_volume, ask_volume = adjust_volume(-76)

print("bid_volume:", bid_volume)
print("ask_volume:", ask_volume)
```

Comment: This is fun. I'll whip up an example in a minute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Bug

`adjust_volume(0)` presently results in:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'bid_volume' referenced before assignment

since `if position_size == 0:` is currently indented inside the `elif position_size < 0:` statement, so is unreachable.  (This could be a result of poor formatting when copying the code into the question post.)

## Possible Bug

Some volume calculations result in negative volumes.  (`adjust_volume(99)` gives `bid_volume == -8`, and `adjust_volume(-99)` gives `ask_volume == -14`, which seem like invalid results.)

## Possible Bug

If `adjust_volume()` is given an argument >= 100 or <= -100, it also fails with an `UnboundLocalError`.  Limits should be checked and a `ValueError` be raised instead.

> This trading system strictly cannot exceed a position limit of 100 in either direction, so our order volumes need to never exceed 100 when combined with the absolute value of `current position`.

100 does not exceed 100, so it is likely the original implementation should have allowed `+100` and `-100` as well.  But these currently result in `UnboundLocalError`.

## Chained comparisons

I have to say, this condition makes my brain hurt:

```
    elif position_size <= -65 and position_size > -82:
```

It took me several moments to unwind what the range was, and I had to triple check that I got it right.  It would be much clearer to express as:

```
    elif -82 < position_size and position_size <= -65:
```

or using the chaining comparison operations:

```
    elif -82 < position_size <= -65:
```

## Bisect

You have 9 ranges:

- -100 < position_size <= -82
- -82 < position_size <= -65
- -65 < position_size <= -45
- -45 < position_size < 0
- 0 <= position_size <= 0
- 0 < position_size < 45
- 45 <= position_size < 65
- 65 <= position_size < 82
- 82 <= position_size < 100

Instead of using a tree of `if`-`elif`-`else` statements to locate the correct range, you could `bisect` the list `-81, -64, -44, 0, 1, 45, 65, 82` to determine the correct range bucket.

*Note*: Negative bucket limits have been increased by 1 to account for the difference in whether the lower limit or the upper limit is included as `position_size` goes from negative values to positive values.

```
from bisect import bisect

POSITION = (-81, -64, -44, 0, 1, 45, 65, 82,)
BID_ASK = (
    (75, 85), # -100 < pos <= -82
    (50, 82), # -82 < pos <= -65
    (50, 65), # -65 < pos <= -45
    (10, 45), # -45 < pos < 0
    (30, 30), # 0 <= pos <= 0
    (45, 50), # 0 < pos < 45
    (65, 50), # 45 <= pos < 65
    (82, 50), # 65 <= pos < 82
    (91, 85), # 82 <= pos < 100
)

def adjust_volume(position_size):

    if not(-100 < position_size < 100):
        raise ValueError("position size out of range")

    bucket = bisect(POSITION, position_size)

    bid_volume, ask_volume = BID_ASK[bucket]
    if position >= 0:
        bid_volume -= position_size
    else:
        ask_volume -= abs(position_size)

    return position_size, bid_volume, ask_volume
```

Comment: Yeah, roughly what I was going to propose. `position_size <= -100 or position_size >= 100` should be `not (-100 < position_size < 100)`

Comment: @Reinderien “should be” may be a little strong; “could be” would be accurate.  It would be slightly shorter which is a plus.  Negative logic statements are often less clear, but here, “if not (valid range): raise Error” does read fairly clearly.  Ok, you’ve convinced me; I’ll change it.

Comment: Big fan of the chained comparisons. I find using only one operator, `<`, and ordering the values lowest to highest increases readability a lot.

Comment: Sorry, yes, your guess was correct, the `if position_size == 0` indentation is incorrect after copying from the script. It should be outside the `elif position_size < 0: statement`